Symfony RedisTagAwareAdapter::doInvalidate causes Argument #1 ($ids) must be of type array, null given at calling doDelete
When invalidating cache the method \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisTagAwareAdapter::doInvalidate is called with valid cache tags the method inside itself is calling the doDelete method:
while ($ids || '0' !== $cursor) {
    $this->doDelete($ids);

and at the point $ids is null instead of any array which is anticipated by the doDelete:
protected function doDelete(array $ids): bool

obviously enough $ids can't be a cause of the problem by itself as the condition in while wouldn't be true, but that '0' !== $cursor string might be a cause of the problem.
As it all happens in prod only, it's hard to debug further. The method protected function doInvalidate is called with a proper list of tags passed as a param (usually just two strings in an array. What might be the cause? The issue occurs extremely rarely.
